# Scipy Bivariate Smooth Spline - fitpack2 error

Tags: python, scipy, spline

I was trying to fit a bivariate smooth spline, but got this error: `scipy\interpolate\_fitpack2.py:1252: UserWarning: ier=988` The ier is different when fitting to different samples (1299,1481,etc.), and these splines with errors are all poorly fitted. Is there something I can do to resolve this? Or is there any other spline packages that can do derivatives and accept non-grid input?

**Update:** I feel changing `kx` and `ky` will help with these problems. However, it will make some well-behaved ones gives warning. Is there a way to catch these UserWarning and fall back to higherorder when needed? I tried "try except", but it seems like there is no exception raised. setting `scipy.special.sterr(all="raise")` does not help.

I am currently doing the following：

```
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings('error')
    try:
        self.spline = SmoothBivariateSpline(x,y,z,s=len(x)/2,kx=3,ky=3)
    except Warning:
        try:
            self.spline = SmoothBivariateSpline(x,y,z,s=len(x)/2,kx=4,ky=4)
        except Warning:
            self.spline = SmoothBivariateSpline(x,y,z,s=len(x)/2,kx=5,ky=5)
```